# Deserialization of enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, singleton, deserialization

Default deserialization of of enum types in Java is restricted as the `readObject` and `readObjectNoData` throw `InvalidObjectException`. For this reason enum types are perfect for implementing singleton classes without any flaw (Item 77, *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Bloch*).

- Why, on the first hand, enum types implement `Serializable` at all?
- How should be enum references deserialized in practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enum types implement `Serializable` so you can serialize objects which contain enum constants. Enum constants are deserialized in the same way as any other objest: by using `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`. Enum constants are encoded differently than instances of normal classes, so `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` can deserialize them without calling their `readObject` method. There are other classes which use special encodings, among them are `String` and `Class`. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#5509) for more details.

If you want to implement serializable singleton classes yourself, look at `readResolve` method.

Comment: Well, point#1 has an answer here. Classes containing enum references shouldn't just crash on serialization.
I tries default deserialization, and it worked simply! Then why, there is a lot of posts discussing effectively deserializing enums ( just to cater code re-factoring)?